# how to publish two more host in Agora Video Live Streaming in Web Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, web, sdk, video-streaming, agora.io

I want to convert the audience into the host role or add multiple hosts in agora.io web SDK. Is there anybody guide me? How I can add multiple hosts in agora.io video live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert the audience into the host role or add multiple hosts in agora.io web SDK. Is there anybody guide me?

Within the Agora SDK you can set the user's role either, before they enter the channel or you can change the role after the client has joined the channel. Regarding the use-case you are describing you would have the user's join as `audience` and then based on your predefined logic, you could switch their role to `broadcaster`.

To set the client role use:

```
client.setClientRole("host", function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    console.log("setHost success");
  } else {
    console.log("setHost error", e);
  }
});
```

`setClient` role documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#setclientrole

Regarding your second question:

> How I can add multiple hosts in agora.io video live streaming.

Agora's SDK supports up to 17 broadcasters within a single channel. There's an advanced guide within Agora's documentation for implementing 7+ broadcasters in a channel: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/multi_user_video_web?platform=Web

Comment: it is right but when a new host added it remove previously host I am getting this problem continously

Comment: Are you using unique UID for each user? can you share some of your code so I can help you troubleshoot?

Comment: function joinChannel() {
  var token = generateToken();
  var userID = 0; // set to null to auto generate uid on successfull connection
  client.setClientRole('host', function() {
    console.log('Client role set as host.');
  }, function(e) {
    console.log('setClientRole failed', e);
  });
  
  client.join(token, channelName, userID, function(uid) {
      createCameraStream(uid, {});
      localStreams.uid = uid; 
      console.log('User ' + uid + ' joined channel successfully');
  }, function(err) {
      console.log('[ERROR] : join channel failed', err);
  });
  
}

Comment: can you update the question to include the code where you switch the user role from audience to host?